# Command line options for ROS and Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Where can I find a list of available command line options for ROS and Gazebo?  After reviewing the latest tutorial on the walking controller and seeing this command:

"roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch gzworld:=atlas_AtlasSimInterface.world"

it is apparent that I don't know all of the different ways we can send options to ROS and Gazebo when starting a ROS core and/or loading a Gazebo environment.  I had no idea that we could overwrite the world specified in the launch file using the command above - what else can we do that I don't know?  I know about the -u for pause, and -e for physics engine, but where can I find out what else I can do?  Where does this information live?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1800/command-line-options-for-ros-and-gazebo/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The option that is being used here is a ROS launch file argument. In order to be able to modify the argument passed to a node the launch file needs to be set up for it to take in an (optional) parameter and pass it down to whichever node makes use of it.

In general you can just open the launch file and look for <arg *> tags which specify the argument that can be passed to the launch file and its default value. So in the case of `atlas.launch` you could do "`rosed atlas_utils atlas.launch`" in order to open the file and then you'll see the lines

```
<arg name="gzname" default="gazebo"/>
<arg name="gzworld" default="atlas.world"/>
```

which tells you that you're able to overwrite the gazebo world being used and whether you want to start it unpaused (default argument `gazebo` which causes the launch file to run the script `run_gazebo` in `atlas_utils`) or paused (by setting `gzname` to `gazebo_paused` which then runs the `run_gazebo_paused` script).

Regiarding the `-u` and `-e` options for `gazebo` you can type "`gazebo --help`" in order to see all of its available options.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-03-19**:
A section on this topic has been added to the DRC User Guide: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#Launch_file_arguments